# Removing a button during actionperformed of that button

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to figure out why my program freezes and  I was able to replicate it with a small script so I can put it here. Basically, in this script When you clicked on button Test1, it is supposed to remove it and added new button Test2. The program freezes. Why? How can I over come this?

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                final JButton bTest1 = new JButton("test1");
                bTest1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      panel.remove(bTest1);
                      panel.add(new JButton("test2"));
                    }

                });
                panel.add(bTest1);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
```

Offcourse in the real program, on the button click, remove all the contents of the panel and re add a new set of components.

Looking for your help!

Comment: When you add a new component (or remove a component) to a visible panel, you need to revalidate the panel: `panel.revalidate()`. Using a CardLayout is what you should do, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Offcourse in the real program, on the button click, remove all the contents of the panel and re add a new set of components.

Then you should probably be using a `CardLayout`. A `CardLayout` is designed to allow you to swap panels.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

> The program freezes. Why? How can I over come this?

It doesn't freeze, its just that the panel isn't smart enough to repaint itself. It you resize the frame you will see the new button.

The problem is you remove the button and add a new button but the panel never repaints itself because the panel is not aware of the changes. You need to invoke the layout manager so the new button can be given a proper size.

The basic code for add/removing components on a visible GUI is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

Comment: Interesting. hmm Thank you for the explanation. The cardlayout is not option for me because I am not just swapping. I didnt put so much details to not confuse people. However the revalidate (and resizing) fixed. What I am still unsure about, is even if I had a panel and I added button later ,it stills shows (and is aware of change). Why is it that it is not aware during action perform when remove/add is made

Comment: When you click the button the button is painted in its "pressed" state. When you release the mouse the ActionListener is invoked and the button is removed from the panel. That is all that happens. The panel does not repaint() itself, so its background does not get cleared so an image of the pressed button remains.  Adding or removing components from a panel does not cause the panel to be repainted. The assumption is that you will add/remove multiple components. It is the applications responsibility to tell the panel it has finished making changes. You use the revalidate() method for this.

Comment: Understood. But lets say you add a button to panel which is added to frame. You set it to invisible and then you remove the button. The panel seems to be aware because the button is actually removed. Why is it that it is not aware only when you do the remove during action listener? My confusion is that why panel sometimes revalidates new additions if it is outside action listener

Comment: When you change the property of a component revalidate() and repaint() are automatically invoked on the component. So the setVisible() method is what causes things to happen, not the removal of the button.

Comment: Thank you . That makes sense. But in my code above, I added panel.add(new JButton("test3")); after the frame.setVisible(true) and it showed the new button. How is it aware?

Comment: Not sure, it should NOT be visible. The usual complaint in the forum, is that a component doesn't show up on the frame. And the common solution is to make sure components are added before the setVisible(). However, creating a frame is a complex process because you need to create an OS widget for the frame and then add Swing components. So the process may not be completely synchronized. That is some code gets added to the end of the EDT and the add() method is executed before this code. For example if you add a `Thread.sleep(10);` before the add(...) you will not see the button.

Comment: Again the general rule is that updates to the GUI must be done on the EDT. You need to revalidate() AFTER adding components to the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.  PS: I tried the thread.sleep but still added the 3rd button. Anyways no worries, I get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Action performed method of the JButton will be executed in AWT thread. When you remove the button from the container, that will launch events that  should be executed as well in the same thread. So one is waiting for the other , and so the program freezes. For solving that situation use

> SwingUtilities.invokeLater

method to execute the removing action of your button

Comment: I tried this before, it didn't solve it. camickr answer was the one needed. thanks though